# Change DNS to openDNS but keep DHCP, NOT static

Tags: dns, wifi-direct, dhcp

I want to change my DNS settings to open DNS but I want to keep the setting at DHCP not static since that won't work on this network. Is this possible?

Comment: Instead of setting DNS via the native WiFi setup, try some alternative DNS apps (which may or may not require root).

Comment: Some example helpers can be found in my [DNS Configuration](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/network_admin_dnstools#group_368) app listing. There might also be ways to achieve that at the command-line, e.g. via `adb shell` (just mentioning it so it might trigger an answer from someone who knows ;)

Comment: Speaking of apps try [Override DNS](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.mx17.overridedns) (which which I personally use)